# iPod Classic wiped and can no longer download any version of iTunes app to my PC

Tags: itunes, applications, ipod

When syncing my iPod Classic 6 generation to iTunes it froze. Although I was already updated with the most recent iTunes, it asked me to uninstall iTunes and download the app again. I have tried several versions on the Internet offered by Microsoft (Apple doesn't have a download?) and elsewhere but none will download the app.

It goes through the motions but to no avail. I can't even access my iTunes account as I can't download the Apple app for PC. I don't understand why I can no longer download any version of the iTunes app to at least get the music back to the iPod.

Answer (score 0):

You would download the app via the Windows App store.  However, if you're having issues with the App Store, Apple has provided direct links to the installers here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210384